# How to migrate data from Cassandra 2.1.9 to a fresh 3.5 installation

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I tried to use sstableloader to load data into Cassandra 3.5. The data was captured using `nodetool snapshot` under Cassandra 2.1.9. All the tables loaded fine except one. It's small, only 2 columns and 20 rows. So, I entered this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11806. The bug was quickly closed as a duplicate. It doesn't seem to be a duplicate, since the original case is upgrading a node in-place, not loading data with sstableloader.

Even so, I tried to apply the the advice given to run `upgradesstable` [sic].

The directions given to upgrade from one version of Cassandra to another seem sketchy at best. Here's what I did based on my working backup/restore and info garnered from various Cassandra docs on how to upgrade:

- Snapshot the data from prod (Cassandra 2.1.9), as usual
- Restore data to Cassandra 2.1.14 running on my workstation
- Verify the restore to 2.1.14 (it worked)
- Copy the data/data/makeyourcase into a Cassandra 3.5 install
- Fire up Cassandra 3.5
- Run `nodetool upgradesstables` to upgrade the sstables to 3.5

`nodetool upgradesstables` fails:

```
>./bin/nodetool upgradesstables
error: Unknown column role in table makeyourcase.roles
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.AssertionError: Unknown column role in table makeyourcase.roles
```

So, the questions: Is it possible to upgrade directly from 2.1.x to 3.5? What's the actual upgrade process? The process at http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeCassandraDetails.html is seemingly missing important details.

Comment: Have you copied also system keyspace directory or only your keyspace data?

Comment: @mmatloka just my keyspace data.

Comment: Cassandra keeps in system keyspaces info about table schemas. Try with exactly the same, whole, data directory (or create schema before moving data, but move it to newly created directories created when schema was created).

Comment: @mmatloka - Just tried it moving the whole data directory. Cass 3.5 comes up fine, but `./bin/nodetool upgradesstables` errors out with the unknown column error.

Comment: @mmatloka - Tried creating the schema first, then copying over just data/data/makeyourcase. Doing this fixes the issues with `upgradesstables`. However, even with the upgraded tables, the restore fails. I have a workaround for now, and that cass bug entered.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem with the changing state of the table over time.

Since the table was small, I was able to migrate the data by using COPY to export the data to CSV and then importing it into the new version.

Have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11806 for discussion of another workaround and a coming bug fix.